# Cannot create database with odbc connection

Tags: database, odbc, informix

Im connected to the sysmaster database with odbc. Now i want to execute an "create database" statement, but im getting an general error while SQLExecDirect.

```
sqlret = SQLExecDirect( stmt, (SQLCHAR*)"CREATE DATABASE testing", SQL_NTS );
```

this fails (sqlret is -1) and SQLGetDiagRec gives the following:
HY00 -11060 [Informix][Informix ODBC Driver]General error.

I have even tried to use SQLPrepare and SQLExecute and then the SQLPrepare is showing this error.
Is it not possible to create a new Database with odbc? In an JDBC program this works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use 'CREATE DATABASE' from within ODBC but only if there is no implicit connection to an existing database.

Try adding 'CONNECTDATABASE=NO' to your connection string.

Comment: Ok thank you. thats the correct solution. And after i have created the database, have i to disconnect this first connection or will it be automatically change to the new db?

Comment: it should automatically switch to the new database.